# one to many relationship in Objectify4

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am working with GAE with java. i am just creating a sample application with Student and Course relationships. I am having many branches and many students. Each branch can have many students, i tried like

```
    ObjectifyService.register(Course.class);
    ObjectifyService.register(Student.class);
    Course course = new Course();
    course.setName("ss");
    course.setBranch("cs");
    ofy().save().entity(course).now();

    Student stu = new Student();
    stu.setName("student1");
    Key<Course> courseKey = new Key<Course>(Course.class, course.getId()); // getting error here
    stu.setCourse(courseKey);
    System.out.println("saving");
    ofy().save().entity(stu).now();
```

I am not sure how to define this relationship in objecitfy4. I followed the tutorial http://www.eteration.com/objectify-an-easy-way-to-use-google-datastore/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Javadocs for Key.  Instead of a public constructor, there is a more convenient creator method which requires less typing of <> generics:

```
Key<Course> courseKey = Key.create(Course.class, course.getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two keys that you might use:

1. first the GAE low-level  `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key` and
2. second, the objectify's `com.googlecode.objectify.Key`.

You can use both with Objectify (as under the hood they are ultimately converted to low-level API).

Neither has a public constructor so you can not use `new` with them.

With low-level keys you'd use [`KeyFactory.createKey("Course", course.getId())`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#createKey%28java.lang.String,%20long%29).
With objectify key you'd use `com.googlecode.objectify.Key.create(Course.class, course.getId())`

Answer (score 0):

When we use Objectify , if we need any Key to be created for condition(KeyFactory.createKey("Course", course.getId()) , In course object, Id field should be specified with index. It will work fine.